# sending multiple push at one time with c2dm

Tags: android, push, push-notification, server-push, android-c2dm

Is there a way to send many pushes message at one time ?

Yesterday it tooks 38 second to send 100 messages, it's way too long.

I get the auth token only one time, the I use:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=$authCode"));
    $post_fields = "registration_id=" . urlencode($deviceToken)
    . "&".$payload
    . "&collapse_key=$key";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if (strpos($response, '200 OK') !== false) {
        return true;
    }   
    else echo $response." ";
    return false;
```

for each push token I got.

Is there a faster way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

curl_multi_exec is the answer.